"Working with a depleted staff team will be difficult." — Does "depleted" refer to number of workers or their physical / emotional exhaustion?
Cambridge Dictionary:

smaller or less than before:
Working with a depleted staff team will be difficult.

Without context, what can "depleted" mean here?
Is it about the number of the people? That is:
The number of the teammates will be much less than before.
Or is it about the inner state of the people? That is:
Every teammate will be emotionally or physically depleted.
Depleted is also defined as

reduced:
physically/emotionally depleted (= weakened)

Or maybe both variants are possible?

"Working with a truncated staff" could mean you chopped their legs off but you have to be sensible. The dictionary quote is right after it says depleted means "smaller or less than before". You think it's talking about beheading or taking the feet off?

@StuartF So, theoretically, beheading or legging is the third possible variant. I didn't know the word "depleted" could mean this.

Meaning-in-context is an ironic tag for a sentence presented without context.   The site let me create an apt tag.

You are given the definition, isn't that enough? depleted staff= reduced staff.

@TimR 1) The word "depleted" is in the sentence. The sentence itself is a context. It's not enough but it exists. Therefore, we cannot say there isn't a context at all; 2) I asked the question not only to understand the sentence, but mostly to understand the meanings of the word "depleted" better because dictionaries didn't help me in that.

The word depleted  means "emptied out".   The
context that  lets us know in what way the thing has been depleted (in number, in emotional and/or physical resiliency) is missing.   If I say "The novel fell flat"  do I mean "was poorly received" or "tipped over in the bookshelf"?  You cannot say, because the utterance has no context. The words in the utterance have a context of the other words, but the utterance itself, taken as a whole, does not.

@TimR "The novel fell flat": With the subject "the novel", we begin to be aware that the context is about a novel, not a dog, not a cat, but a novel. So to ask what "to fall flat" in "The novel fell flat" means is not the same as just to ask what "to fall flat" (without any example) means.

You're missing the point that the utterance, taken as a whole, lacks context.  The context I'm referring to is the conversational context, not the syntactic/semantic context that is, itself, incapable of resolving that sort of ambiguity, resolution that yields actual meaning, as distinct from potential meaning.

Am I talking about the novel, the abstract work, or the novel, the edition on the shelf?  Only conversational context will resolve the ambiguity of "fell flat".   The novel fell flat. It was largely unreviewed, and the few reviews it did receive were tepid.   Now we have a context.

In the Cambridge Dic. it says: smaller or less than before:
Working with a depleted staff team will be difficult. You don't understand that?

@Lambie  Lovii is asking how to know it means a smaller staff and not an overstressed or emotionally depleted staff of the same size as usual.

@TimR Because the actual dictionary says it means: smaller or less than before, right under that example.  How is that not perfectly clear?

@Lambie  Because "feel depleted" is a very common phrase  in the   context of employee burnout. See https://www.webmd.com/mental-health/burnout-symptoms-signs

@Lambie In order that I might memorize an English word, I must find a similar word in my home language. Sometimes it's very hard or even impossible. Finding a good analogue of "depleted" in (1) in my own language is just such a case. So I tried discussing what "depleted" could mean on that example. I hoped it would help me to understand the word “depleted” better.

@Lambie I think you (along with some other members) miss the crucial point when someone asks what a word means. It is as follows: most likely you won't know the language which an original poster speaks in, therefore you can't determine exactly whether he really has difficulties with meanings of some word or he's just lazy, silly or inattentive. So how you consider the questions about word meanings depends not only on how felicitous an original poster managed to formulate his question, but also on your own wish: whether to believe that the poster has real difficulties or not.

@Loviii  I find your mix of grammatical knowledge and linguistic obtuseness quite puzzling.  I don't see how you do not realize that when a word or phrase can have more than one meaning, as here, there's no conclusive way to decide between two plausible possibilities without the context in which the remark was uttered.  Probabilities suggest the speaker is talking about having too few staff. But that the speaker is using Human Resources psycho-jargon is not implausible.   Cant spreads in corporate contexts as fast as measles in an unvaccinated population.

@TimR To feel depleted as in the article you quote is not like "depleted staff" defined in the dictionary, smaller or less than before. "a depleted staff" is obviously not "feeling depleted". Again, the Cambridge Dictionary **specifically defines depleted in this sentence: Working with a depleted staff team will be difficult. AS smaller or less than before. It's there in black and white. It's their sentence, in fact.

I believe you may find it difficult but I don't see how we can help when the English dictionary you consulted provided this sentence and its meaning (a depleted staff) so a staff that is smaller than before. Also, it is hard to believe that you don't have a bilingual dictionary containing the word depletion.

I’m voting to close this question because any answer would depend on context and might be pure opinion.

You've misunderstood how "depleted" is used when referring to mental exhaustion or distress. There are clues in statements such as: "They feel depleted" and "Their numbers are depleted” staff team will most likely refer to number(s) while emotionally/physically will refer to feelings. If you're really interested in getting to grips with the meanings of words then you must look up more than one dictionary. Merriam-Webster is good (not great) for examples of the word used in sentences. Fraze.it is a useful tool.

The situation has left the family depleted mentally, physically and financially

As you imply, context matters, but without any further information I would understand that the team had too few people to function easily. This may be a temporary situation due to illness or vacations  or it may be due to understaffing by the company.
Whilst you could say the members of the team were emotionally depleted this is more commonly used to describe stress related mental problems. It would be far more usual to say that they were demoralised or that their moral was low.
If they were physically depleted, I would understand them to be physically unfit for the tasks in hand, exhausted by excessive labour or undernourished.

You said: "Whilst you could say the members of the team were emotionally or physically depleted this is not idiomatic English." I need to clarify this. Aside the example from the original post, is it natural to describe someone with the phrases "emotionally depleted" and "physically depleted"? Thanks.

Yes, @Loviii, that is perfectly idiomatic English.

@PaulTanenbaum Yes, I had not come across that usage, but I concede that it is, apparently, idiomatic English and "emotionally depleted" usage has increased rapidly over, about, the past 40 years according to Google Ngrams. I've changed my answer to try and reflect this.
